# How to properly disable an Html Helper Textbox or TextBoxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, linq-to-entities, html-helper

I have a razor display that is being used for entry. In one case, I would like the user to be able to populate the text box, in the other case, I would like to prevent the user from populating it. I am using code like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Goop, new { @class = "text-box", maxlength = 2, onfocus = "javascript:this.select();" })
if (Model.Review.ReviewType.Equals("M"))
{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#Goop").prop("disabled", true);
         });
    </script>
}
```

I have tried to do this several ways, jQuery (above), CSS attribs, javascript, ASP.NET... but all have the same issue: When the form is submitted, if the Goop textbox is disabled, the value for Goop in the model is Null. Ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not as cool without jQuery, but when I do this in my apps I do something along the lines of

```
if (Model.Review.ReviewType.Equals("M"))
{ 
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Goop)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Goop)
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Goop)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that does "work"... it "seems" like a kluge, though I'll take "works" over "seems"... at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

If a form element is disabled, it does not post a value.  That's how it's supposed to work.

To work around this, you will need to do one of several things.  You can enable the fields just before posting by intercepting the submit method.  You can use a hidden field to store the data in addition to the disabled control.  Or you can just assume the values on the controller side.

by the way, it should be `.prop("disabled", "disabled")`, which renders as disabled="disabled", that's standards compliant.

Comment: As noted in: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12 ; In my view, the current behavior doesn't meet this. On postback, it alters the model attrib. It should be unsuccessful and not change the model attrib.

Comment: @sscheider - what do you mean by "it alters the model attribute"?  HTML doesn't know or care about your model, and is irrelevant to it.